# Combination of charts in highcharts overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have tried bar chart with column chart and in result both are overlapping each other. How do I fix it?

```
for single chart type
http://jsfiddle.net/j3dkb67j/

with combination of bar & column
http://jsfiddle.net/3orza5Lo/1/
```

Thanks.

Comment: look at this FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/3orza5Lo/4/

Comment: If you want to have bar series and chart series on the same chart.. then you have strange requirements. In short, bar chart is the same as column chart, with only one change - it inverts chart (`chart.inverted` option).

Comment: Please edit your question to describe your use case in better detail so that it may be answered appropriately.

Comment: @PawełFus Actually I was trying to give user configurable options but now I think I have restrict in this particular use case so one doesn't have both at one time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this portion of code here:

```
    series: [{
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
    }, {
        type: 'bar',
        name: 'John',
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
    }]
```

You'll notice that the very last object `type` still has a value of `column` when it should be `bar`.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31f1tjnt/2/) for the corrected graph.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. I am trying combination of different chart. The problem occurs when I try to mix column and bar chart.

Comment: If that's what you were after you should have made a more detailed post describing what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: In the highcharts you cannot mix inverted (bar) and not inverted (column)  series in the same chart. It can be only one type.